# How to Merge or Combine return data from model in Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 function, it is `a()` `b()` and `c()`

and then, function a() returned :

```
{
    id    =>
    total1 =>
}
```

function b() returned like funcion a() too, but have a different value (total1 and total2)

function c() returned :

```
{
    id   => //same value just like function a or b
    name =>
}
```

```
$a = $model->a(); // from function a();
$b = $model->b(); // from function b();
$c = $model->c(); // from function c();
```

i want combine that 3 returned values into array like this :

```
array = ['id','name', 'total1', 'total2']
```

any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
array_keys(array_merge($a, $b, $c));
```

If variables are not arrays, convert them to arrays with `toArray()` or `json_decode()` first.

If functions return Laravel collections, you can use [`merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-merge) and [`keys()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keys) helpers.

Comment: hi there, i'm used `return Class::all()` in my model, should i use toArray() or json_encode function?

Comment: @DarkCode999 use `toArray()`

Comment: Collections have a `merge()` method too. :)

Comment: @DarkCode999 `all()` doesn't return structure you've shown. Try to use something like `Class::first()->toArray()`. @IvankaTodorova yep, I have it in my answer. It's just wasn't clear how OP gets the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the results to array

```
$a = $model->a()->toArray(); // from function a();
$b = $model->b()->toArray(); // from function b();
$c = $model->c()->toArray(); // from function c();
```

and then

```
$data= array_merge($a , $b, $c)
```

Comment: This will return arrays with values.